# Command 'latex2html'

Tags: command-line, latex

Wonder whether this is an ubuntu question or a latex question:

I am trying to output my LaTeXed cv in HTML format, using `latex2html` - probably the easiest way.

My objective is this

I want all sections and their contents to appear one after another. (Default appearance is the list of all section headers in the form of links and only on clicking them do I see the contents of the section)

I tried attacking it the way. This is the closest I got:

I gave the command:

```
man latex2html
```

to explore the various features. The option that seems promising in this matter is `-split`. Split 0 is the one that keeps the entire doc in a single file as found on giving `man latex2html` command.

```
aneesh@AcerAOD:~$ latex2html [ -split 0 ] cv.tex
defined(%hash) is deprecated at /usr/bin/latex2html line 515.
    (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
defined(%hash) is deprecated at /usr/bin/latex2html line 2087.
    (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
defined(%hash) is deprecated at /usr/bin/latex2html line 9088.
        (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
This is LaTeX2HTML Version 2008 (1.71)
by Nikos Drakos, Computer Based Learning Unit, University of Leeds.

Revised and extended by:
 Marcus Hennecke, Ross Moore, Herb Swan and others
...producing markup for HTML version 4.0  

Extension: loading /usr/share/latex2html/versions/latin1.pl
HTML version: loading /usr/share/latex2html/versions/html4_0.pl

 *** processing declarations ***

Resetting image-cacheCannot read ./[.tex
```

Unfortunately this didn't work. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the same command but without the **[**...**]** around split, they are there in the manual page to indicate that the `-split` argument is optional:

```
latex2html -split 0 cv.tex
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! Initially I had tried without braces, and found an error. Don't know/care why ;-)